# LNK1104: cannot open file 'boost_thread-vc100-mt-gd-1_55.lib'

Tags: boost, qpid

I'm facing difficulty to build qpid cpp solution on windows xp

I have installed Boost 1.55.0, Python 2.7, Ruby 2.0.0 and CMake 2.8

Then I have added Environment variable paths for Python, Ruby and CMake, and then Boost variables are
set as followed

> BOOST_ROOT C:\Boost
>
> BOOST_LIBRARYDIR C:\Boost\lib
>
> BOOST_INCLUDEDIR C:\Boost\include

I build Boost with following commands from command prompt

> bootstrap
>
> .\b2

I have downloaded qpid-cpp-0.26, Then I build qpid with following command from command prompt

```
cmake -i -G "Visual Studio 10"
```

Executing the above command have generated solution file for qpid

Then I opened qpid from solution file to build in Visual Studio 2010, when I tried to build the solution it
gave me following error in qpidCommon

cannot open file 'boost_thread-vc100-mt-gd-1_55.lib'

After bit of searching, I came up with solutions like

Adding “BOOST_ALL_DYN_LINK” in Preprocessor definations

Adding Library path in Linker – General - Additional Library Directories

but above solutions didn't work for me

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a workaround, from command prompt run following command

```
bjam --build-type=complete
```

Add lib path in Project Properties - Configuration Properties - VC++ Directories
- Library Directories - here add library path(one which is in stage - lib)

This worked for me.