# C++ OGRE3D VS2013: Error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_MSC_VER': value '1700' doesn't match value '1800'

Tags: c++, boost, visual-studio-2013, linker, ogre

I started to play around with OGRE and downloaded it. I use MS Visual Studio 2013 Express. I saw that there's no SDK for VS2013 so I downloaded the VS2012 one. Then I downloaded the [Tutorial Framework](http://www.ogre3d.org/tikiwiki/tiki-index.php?page=Ogre+Wiki+Tutorial+Framework), setted up the project like [this](http://www.ogre3d.org/tikiwiki/tiki-index.php?page=Setting+Up+An+Application+-+Visual+Studio) and tried to compile it.

However, it didn't link. It gave an error "LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_thread-vc120-mt-gd-1_55.lib'". I tried to find the solution from SO, and I found [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23468417/lnk1104-cannot-open-file-boost-thread-vc100-mt-gd-1-55-lib) and tested it. I changed copied all of the `libboost_*-vc110-mt-gd-1_55.lib`s, pasted them to same directory and renamed them to `libboost_*-vc120-mt-gd-1_55.lib`.

This worked to the first problem, but it gave another one, what I'm asking right now. I know this means that I'm using a library file what is compiled in wrong version of MSVC. I couldn't find the real `libboost_*-vc120-mt-gd-1_55.lib`.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Visual Studio C++ compiled binaries are not linkable across versions because they rely on a specific version of the runtime. The C ABI stays constant but things that rely on C++ does not have a stable ABI at this point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the error message states you are using incompatible binary versions. You cannot simply mix'n'match (neither the boost libraries nor the Ogre binaries).

Downloading the correct binaries for boost should help: [Boost pre-built VS2013](http://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost-binaries/1.57.0/boost_1_57_0-msvc-12.0-32.exe/download)

The most flexible and quite easy option for Ogre on Windows however is to simply compile Ogre yourself. You can even disable to boost integration completely via CMake if you don't need it.